# Почему Babel не компилирует код (Gulp + Webpack + Babel)?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel, gulp4, webpack-stream

Использую связку gulp + wabpack(wabpack-stream) + babel 7.

IE11 ругается на class. Полагаю babel попросту не отработал. До этого с babel не работал, не могу понять что не так.

[image: ИЕ 11]

Настройки wabpack:

```js
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/assets/js")],
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
```

.babelrc:

```js
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

package.json:

```js
"browserslist": [
    "last 2 version",
    "> 1%",
    "IE 10"
  ],
```

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-stream": "^5.2.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

IE не поддерживает определение классов  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes